# Selective case sensitivity/insensitivity with PRXPARSE

Tags: regex, sas

I have the following regex which I am using to scan fields within a dataset for a variety of markers that may indicate that the record belongs to a US resident:

```
prx_1 = (prxparse("/(?i)^USA$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^United[\s+]States[\s+]of[\s+]America$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^US$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^U[\s+]S[\s+]A$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^United[\s+]States$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^America$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^U[\.+]S[\.+]A$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^U[\.+]S[\.+]A[\.+]$(?-i)|
                      (?-i)^AL$|(?-i)^AK$|(?-i)^AZ$|(?-i)^AR$|
                      (?-i)^CA$|(?-i)^CO$|(?-i)^CT$|(?-i)^DE$|
                      (?-i)^DC$|(?-i)^FL$|(?-i)^GA$|(?-i)^HI$|
                      (?-i)^ID$|(?-i)^IL$|(?-i)^IN$|(?-i)^IA$|
                      (?-i)^KS$|(?-i)^KY$|(?-i)^LA$|(?-i)^ME$|
                      (?-i)^MD$|(?-i)^MA$|(?-i)^MI$|(?-i)^MN$|
                      (?-i)^MS$|(?-i)^MO$|(?-i)^MT$|(?-i)^NE$|
                      (?-i)^NV$|(?-i)^NH$|(?-i)^NJ$|(?-i)^NM$|
                      (?-i)^NY$|(?-i)^NC$|(?-i)^ND$|(?-i)^OH$|
                      (?-i)^OK$|(?-i)^OR$|(?-i)^PA$|(?-i)^RI$|
                      (?-i)^SC$|(?-i)^SD$|(?-i)^TN$|(?-i)^TX$|
                      (?-i)^UT$|(?-i)^VT$|(?-i)^VA$|(?-i)^WA$|
                      (?-i)^WV$|(?-i)^WI$|(?-i)^WY$|(?-i)^AS$|
                      (?-i)^GU$|(?-i)^MP$|(?-i)^PR$|(?-i)^VI$|
                      (?-i)^UM$|(?-i)^FM$|(?-i)^MH$|(?-i)^PW$|
                      (?-i)^AA$|(?-i)^AE$|(?-i)^AP$|(?-i)^CM$|
                      (?-i)^CZ$|(?-i)^NB$|(?-i)^PI$|(?-i)^TT$|
                      (?i)^Alabama$(?-i)|(?i)^Alaska$(?-i)|(?i)^Arizona$(?-i)|(?i)^Arkansas$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^California$(?-i)|(?i)^Colorado$(?-i)|(?i)^Connecticut$(?-i)|(?i)^Delaware$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^District[\s+]of[\s+]Columbia$(?-i)|(?i)^Florida$(?-i)|(?i)^Georgia$(?-i)|(?i)^Hawaii$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^Idaho$(?-i)|(?i)^Illinois$(?-i)|(?i)^Indiana$(?-i)|(?i)^Iowa$(?-i)|(?i)^Kansas$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^Kentucky$(?-i)|(?i)^Louisiana$(?-i)|(?i)^Maine$(?-i)|(?i)^Maryland$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^Massachusetts$(?-i)|(?i)^Michigan$(?-i)|(?i)^Minnesota$(?-i)|(?i)^Mississippi$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^Missouri$(?-i)|(?i)^Montana$(?-i)|(?i)^Nebraska$(?-i)|(?i)^Nevada$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^New[\s+]Hampshire$(?-i)|(?i)^New[\s+]Jersey$(?-i)|(?i)^New[\s+]Mexico$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^New[\s+]York$(?-i)|(?i)^North[\s+]Carolina$(?-i)|(?i)^North[\s+]Dakota$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^Ohio$(?-i)|(?i)^Oklahoma$(?-i)|(?i)^Oregon$(?-i)|(?i)^Pennslyvania$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^Rhode[\s+]Island$(?-i)|(?i)^South[\s+]Carolina$(?-i)|(?i)^South[\s+]Dakota$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^Tennessee$(?-i)|(?i)^Texas$(?-i)|(?i)^Utah$(?-i)|(?i)^Vermont$(?-i)|(?i)^Virginia$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^Washington$(?-i)|(?i)^West[\s+]Virginia$(?-i)|(?i)^Wisconsin$(?-i)|(?i)^Wyoming$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^American[\s+]Samoa$(?-i)|(?i)^Guam$(?-i)|(?i)^Northern[\s+]Mariana[\s+]Islands$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^Puerto[\s+]Rico$(?-i)|(?i)^Virgin[\s+]Islands$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^U[\.*]S[\.*][\s+]Minor[\s+]Outlying[\s+]Islands$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^Federated[\s+]States[\s+]of[\s+]Micronesia$(?-i)|(?i)^Marshall[\s+]Islands$(?-i)|
                      (?i)^Palau$(?-i)/"
            ));
```

This is a series of small regexes concatenated with the `|` marker. My understanding of regexes was that if I wanted to switch case sensitivity on and off I should use `(?i)` to turn it on and `(?-i)` to turn it off. However this code is not returning matches where the state name for example is written in upper case.

Have I misinterpreted something here?

Thanks

Comment: Withrdawn - it _is_ possible to do this!

Comment: @joe thanks for the response. i cant find any direct reference to these sensitivity markers within any SAS documentation either. I think i was just looking at general regex metacharacters when i compiled this. I think the best option at this point will be for me to upcase all the fields i am scanning and amend the regex to look for hard coded uppercase strings only.

Comment: @joe...do you have a link/example syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If the regex flavour support `(?i)`, it should also support `(?i:pattern)`. You should rewrite your regex and place the patterns which should be case-insensitive inside the non-capturing group `(?i:pattern)`.

An example for the part of the pattern which you need to make case-insensitive:

```
^(?i:USA|United\s+States\s+of\s+America|United\s+States)$
```

An example for the part of the pattern which you need to make case-sensitive:

```
^(?:AL|AK|AZ|AR)$
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. i will try that now. i dont underastand your syntax for the case sensitive line though. shouldnt that read '^(?-i:AL|AK|AZ|AR)$'?

Comment: @user3045351: By default, case-insensitive is off (unless you specify it outside, but don't). The `(?i:...)` will scope the case-insensitive to only the pattern inside.

Comment: I've confirmed that this does work in SAS.  @user3045351 The reason you don't need the `(?-i)` is because the default for the group is to be insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This works here.  See [this page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003288497.htm) lower down, title "Comments and Inline Modifiers", for detail.

```
data have;
input state $;
datalines;
AZ
az
Az
ARIZONA
Arizona
ArIzOnA
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  _rx = prxparse('~(?i)AZ|(?-i)Arizona~o');
  _rc = prxmatch(_rx,state);
  put _rc=;
run;
```

Your regex is too complex right now to really help you troubleshoot.  If you want troubleshooting, I would limit it to just one state (or something like that) and figure it out from there.

Comment: what does the '~' and '~o' do in this example?

Comment: The `~` is identical to the `/` in yours; you can use any character that doesn't appear in the regex, and I prefer to use `~` as I more likely use `/`.  The `o` afterwards says 'only compile once', I think it's only 9.3+.  Replaces the `if _n_=1 then do;` requirement (so you can put it just in the middle of the data step wherever you like).